# Loading an object from a db4o database

Tags: object, loading, db4o, permissions

I am developing an e-commerce website that utilises db4o as the backend.  All was well until last week when I came across a problem that I have been unable to solve.  The code below is quite straight forward. I open a database file, save an object and then try to retrieve it.  However I get nothing back.  The "users" variable has a count of zero.

```
public class Program
{
    private static string _connectionString = string.Format(@"c:\aaarrrr.db4o");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestUser container = new TestUser() { id = 1, Name = "Mohammad", Surname = "Rafiq" };

        Db4oFactory.Configure().Diagnostic().AddListener(new DiagnosticToConsole());

        using (var dbc = Db4oFactory.OpenFile(_connectionString))
        {
            dbc.Store(container);
        }

        IList<TestUser> users = null;

        using (var dbc = Db4oFactory.OpenFile(_connectionString))
        {
            users = dbc.Query<TestUser>(x => x.id == 1).ToList();
        }

        if (users.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} with id of {2}", users.First().Name, users.First().Surname, users.First().id);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nNo data returned.");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class TestUser
{
    [Indexed]
    private int _id = 0;
    private string _name = string.Empty;
    private string _surname = string.Empty;

    public int id { get { return _id; } set { _id = value; } }
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
    public string Surname { get { return _surname; } set { _surname = value; } }
}
```

I have attached db4o diagnostic listener and I see nothing in the console output.  Everything seems fine.  I know I am writing to the file because I can see the file size increase and the timestamp is also updated.  I have checked all the project settings and they are all set to default.  I am using .net 4, visual studio 2010 beta and windows 7.  I have done some reading regarding reflection permission but I cant see how this applies here. Any help or ideas would be knidly appreciated.

Comment: Update.  I have created a new console application project and copied and pasted this code into that project.  I ran the application and too my surprise it worked fine.  It must be something to do with the project settings, or perhaps the dll's the project references.

Comment: I've ran the code on VS 2008 and .NET 3.5. It works fine here.   

Have you added the 'Db4objects.Db4o.NativeQueries.dll'-assembly on both projects? When the 'Db4objects.Db4o.NativeQueries.dll'-assembly is present, the query above will be optimized, otherwise not. Therefore is makes quite a difference.

Comment: I have managed to replicate the problem.  Its to do with the namespace.  If you set the the "Assembly name" and "Default namespace" in the project properties to a simple name such as "test" the code then works fine.  However if you set it to "Dukaan.Provider.db4o" then the code doesnt work.  It would be nice if you could confirm this. Thank you.  P.S yes I have added these assemblies.

Comment: Its the assembly name that is the problem and not the deafult namespace.

Comment: It doesn't work with the namespace 'Dukaan.Provider.db4o' right? It's probably due this bug: http://tracker.db4o.com/browse/COR-1798

However the bug should be fixed in the current 7.12 release. Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 7.4.121 (I got this from the db4oobjects.db4o dll). But its not the namespace.  Its when I change the assembly name it begins to work.  So in the project properties I have left the default namespace as "Dukaan.Providers.db4o" and the assemby name I have changed to "duprodb" and it begins to work.  If I change the assembly name to the name of default namespace then it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

After calling store(), you need to commit() before leaving the using{} statement. You closed your database before committing your changes.